# $a_{3n} = {-1}/ \sqrt[3]n, \ a_{3n+1} = {-2}/ \sqrt[3]n, \ a_{3n+2}= {3} / \sqrt[3]n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $a_n$ defined by:
$$a_{3n} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]n},\quad a_{3n+1} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt[3]n},\quad a_{3n+2}=\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]n} $$
show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

I thought about looking at partial sums, but I don't see how they converge...

Comment: How is $a_1$ defined?

Comment: It's supposed to be subsequences for when $n=3k$,$n=3k+1$,$n=3k+2$ for $k \ge 0$

Comment: Does the sum start with $n=4$, or are you supposed to take $k=\frac{1}{3}$ when $n=1, 2, 3$?

Comment: It should be $n=1$ and then $a_1=-2$ $a_2=3$ $a_3=-1$ etc..

Comment: Shouldn't the denominators have $n+1$ in place of $n$, then?

Comment: I meant in previous comment: It should be $n=1$ and then $a_1=-2$,  $a_2=3/\sqrt[3]2$,  $a_3=-1/\sqrt[3]3$ etc..

Comment: I don't think $a_1=-2$ corresponds to the formulas given in the problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(c_n)$ be the sequence given by $-2, 3,-1, -2, 3, -1, -2, 3, -1, \cdots$.

Then $(c_n)$ has bounded partial sums, and the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)$ is decreasing to 0,

so the series $\sum\frac{c_n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ converges by Dirichlet's test.